# Find index of item within the array by value?

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to find the index of an item in a classic asp array. i get how it's possible with looping, but is there something else i can use? indexOf() or something along those lines? i can't seem to find anything online

Comment: How are you addressing the array to begin with (please add some code)?

Comment: Are you using VBScript/JScript/other?

Comment: If you need quick searching, use something like Dictionary instead of array.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an array of strings, or some other type of objects?

For standard data types you can use Array.BinarySearch(myArray, searchString), but you have to sort the array first.

Comment: As per Tom Swifty's post, try looking [here](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110602-1.aspx).

Comment: Hi @Tom, Madam wants the indexOf for classic VB, it is not VB.NET. So there is no Array.BinarySearch. I am afirad, you need to do this manually, please check this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.vb.bugs/1GYTy520SDk).